# python pass object or instantiate from within second object

Tags: python, class, object, instantiation

I wondered if its better to:

1. Pass Object1 into Object2 for use

or

2. Instantiate Object1 from Object2

I could do either, but I am wondering what is better practice, or where i could get caught up.

These are rather rudimentary examples, and of course in the second example, i could just use the list. The actual code I am using, i need to use a lot of Object1 values to do things in Object2.

Example 1:

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self, person):
       self.id = person[0]
       self.name = person[1]
       self.age = person[2]


class Object2:
    def __init__(self, object1):
      self.object1 = object1

      retirement_age = self.object1.age + 25

      print(self.object1.id)
      print(self.object1.name)
      print(retirement_age)

 person = [1, 'Ryan', 30]
 o = Object1(person)
 r = Object2(o)
```

Example 2:

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self, person):
       self.id = person[0]
       self.name = person[1]
       self.age = person[2]


class Object2:
    def __init__(self, person):
       self.o = Object1(person)

       retirement_age = self.o.age + 25

       print(self.o.id)
       print(self.o.name)
       print(retirement_age)

person = [1, 'Ryan', 30]
r = Object2(person)
```

Comment: I would say the former. Since `Object2` does not need *any* knowledge about how to construct an `Object1`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem interesting. In talking to a Java programmer friend of mine, he says it's much better to use "composition" (instantiate from inside object) over inheritance. What I'm not sure about is passing a whole object. Seems like a tricky way to pass a lot of info to another class. Instead of using parameters/arguments. Kinda like building a big dict and sharing that

Comment: Neither of your options involve inheritance, so the question of composition vs inheritance seems to be coming out of nowhere. Did you *intend* to be using inheritance in one of your examples? Inheritance can be tricky, but if it is appropriate for a given relationship between two classes, it's probably better to actually use it rather than reinventing it while overtly using composition. Inheritance means an "IS-A" relationship. That is, if instances of `Object2` should also be considered instances of `Object1` (for instance, an `Employee` is a `Person`), then you should use inheritance.

Comment: I guess I was supposing I could use inheritance if I remodeled, but I don't want to. I really want to stick to either of my examples as they fit perfectly for that I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends, and only you can decide.

In the first example, you can use `o` in many places throughout your program without creating the same object over and over again (just make sure you are not modifying it anywhere, see below why).

The second option encapsulates the fact that `Object1` even exists.

You need to ask yourself a few questions:

- Will you use `Object1` instances anywhere else in the code base? Does it even make sense to have a "standalone" `Object1` instance outside of `Object2` instance?
- Does `Object2` need to know about `Object1`? Does it need to know how to construct it? should it even care?
- Can `Object2` instances simply contain the attributes of `Object1` directly? If the answer is 'yes' then `Object1` is redundant.

**You have to be very careful with option 1.**
If the object you pass through to `Object2` is modified *anywhere*, the changes will affect all of the corresponding `Object2` instances.

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self, person):
       self.id = person[0]
       self.name = person[1]
       self.age = person[2]


class Object2:
    def __init__(self, object1):
      self.object1 = object1

      retirement_age = self.object1.age + 25

      print(self.object1.id)
      print(self.object1.name)
      print(retirement_age)

person = [1, 'Ryan', 30]
o = Object1(person)
r = Object2(o)

# modifying o.name will affect r.object1.name as well
o.name = 'John'
print(r.object1.name)
#  1
#  Ryan
#  55
#  John
```

Comment: Good point. I was leaning towards the first answer until you mentioned that last point. To throw a wrinkle into it, a 3rd object also needs to know object 1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

You could use the first method as `Object2` doesn't need any information about how to construct an `Object1`.

On the other hand, if you needed to use `person` in `Object2`, you should use the second method as it would be easier to use `person` instead of `self.object1.id`, especially if you had to use `person` many times.